# Built-in function to find first character NOT in a set

Tags: python, string

Is there a built-in function in Python (3.11.1) that, given a string and a set of characters and a starting position, can find the index of the first character in the string that is *not* in the set of characters, beginning the search at the specified start position?

C++ has [`string::find_first_not_of`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) and Fortran has [`NCPOS`](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/spicelib/ncpos.html), is there a Python equivalent?

For example, if I did (making up `ncpos`):

```
    pos = "   012345   hello".ncpos(" eh", 10)
```

Then `pos` would have the value `14` (the first character that isn't in `" eh"`, starting at location 10). Is there something like this?

Comment: No, there is no such builtin.

Comment: Depends on your definition of builtin. Would using `re` count? Or a short generator?

Comment: It's unclear what you are even asking.  Do you want to know the first _character_ that is missing, or the _location_ of that character within the original string?

Comment: @JohnGordon As per the descriptions of the linked functions, and the example return value for the example string: the location of the first character in a string that is *not* in a given set of characters. I will update the leading sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a function similar to this behaviour

```
def find_first_not_of(s: str, chrs: str, start: int = 0) -> int:
    return next((i for i in range(start, len(s)) if s[i] not in chrs), -1)

# alternative approach which is more efficient, especially for larger strings as pointed out by Chris

def find_first_not_of(s: str, chrs: str, start: int = 0) -> int:
    return next((start + i for i, v in enumerate(s[start:]) if v not in chrs), -1)

find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 0)
find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 3)
find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 5)
find_first_not_of("   012345   hello", " eh", 10)

2
3
5
14
```

You can also achive the same using regex as suggested in the comments

```
import re

def find_first_not_of(s: str, chrs: str, start: int = 0) -> int:
    chrs = re.escape(chrs)
    match = re.search(f'[^{chrs}]', s[start:])
    return match.start() + start if match else -1


# Also pointed out by Chris you can one line it with the walrus in 3.8+
return (match.start() + start
            if (match := re.search(f"[^{re.escape(chrs)}]", s[start:]))
            else -1)

find_first_not_of("   012345   hello", " eh", 10)
find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 0)
find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 3)
find_first_not_of("abcdefgh", "ab", 5)

14
2
2
3
```

Comment: As a one-liner if you're using Python 3.8 or later: `return match.start() + start if (match := re.search(f'[^{chrs}]', s[start:])) else -1`

Comment: Yea, I just thought it was easier to demonstrate on separate lines in this case without the walrus.

Comment: I might also suggest your first example could be `return next((start + i for i, v in enumerate(s[start:]) if v not in chrs), -1)`

Comment: Ah yes, I'll add it but keep both for demonstration purposes as hopefully people can learn from them.

Comment: Updated and credited @Chris

Comment: Thanks for these. Just want to note that the second version (with the regex) has the caveat that, since it's not escaped for regex, `chrs` needs to be formatted to be compatible with a regex character set (e.g. passing in `"a-z"` would be `a` through `z` rather than `a`, `-`, and `z`) (or passing in `"]*["` would change the regex).

Comment: @JasonC I updated it with escape